# Vertically align multi-lines text next to an image?

Tags: html, css

I found this example in stackoverflow, it works in single line text.

```css
 .align-middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
    .align-middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="align-middle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
  <span class="align-middle">I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</span>
</div>
I need to add several lines of the text of in the div block. I try this doesn't work.


<div>
  <img class="align-middle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
  <span class="align-middle">(1)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</span>
  <span class="align-middle">(2)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</span>
  <span class="align-middle">(3)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</span>

</div>
```

Please tell me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let try with:

```
<style>
.align-middle {
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
 }
</style>

<div>
  <img class="align-middle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">

  <span class="align-middle">
    <p>(1)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(2)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(3)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer will not work if any of the `<p>` elements are longer than a single line.

Comment: If the text in <p> is so long, you should set the width for <span> like as 
span.align-middle {
width: 80%;
}

Comment: Setting the `width` of the `<span>` manually is the worst thing you can do. It will not be responsive nor reusable and it will only work if you also set the `width` of the image so that they sum up `100%` or less. What if you have multiple similar layouts with images of different width? Are you going to add a specific `width` for each case?

Comment: `span` is a [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#phrasing-content). In HTML 5.x, it can't contain p elements which are flow content (it couldn't either in HTML 4.01/XHTML 1.0 but that was related to simpler _%inline_ and _%block_ content models). You should use a div to wrap your paragraphs and avoid non-validating HTML markup which will be parsed in unexpected ways by browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each individual text element (`<span>`s in your case) doesn't take over more than one line, just wrap them in another element (`.text-group` in my example) and apply the `vertical-align: middle` to that one.

You also need to set `display: block` to the `<span>` elements if there are more than one (or replace them with other elements, such as `<p>`, that are displayed as blocks by default).

```css
.align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-group {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="align-middle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
  
  <div class="align-middle text-group">
    <span>(1)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</span>
    <span>(2)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</span>
    <span>(3)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if any of those `<span>` take over more than one line, then this approach will not work, as you can see next:

```css
.align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-group {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="align-middle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
  
  <div class="align-middle text-group">
    <span>(1)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</span>
    <span>(2)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray! (3) I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

As pointed out by @KhoiNgoNguyen, you can set a `width` to the `.text-group` so that, together with the image, they sum up `100%` or less. However, that's a really bad approach for multiple reasons:

- You will also need to set a `width` on the image to make sure it doesn't take more space.
- If you use this layout in multiple places but with different images, you will have to manually set the `width` on all the ocurrences.
- What if you have more columns? You will have to adjust the `width` for all of them.

If support is not a problem, [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the best option:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
  
  <div>
    <p>(1)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(2)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray! (3) I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now it will display as intended even if the text part is longer than the image:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
  
  <div>
    <p>(1)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(2)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray! (3) I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(4)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray! (5) I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(6)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray! (7) I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can even add multiple columns with no extra code!

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
  
  <div>
    <p>(1)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(2)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray! (3) I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(4)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray! (5) I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(6)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray! (7) I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <p>(1)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(2)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray! (3) I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(4)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray! (5) I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
    <p>(6)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray! (7) I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

[click on this Just Write this code (code you see in image)  and you can solve your problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhj65.jpg)

[and this is the result of that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7dun.jpg)

CSS of your code

```
<style>

    span {
          display: inline-block;
    }
    .align-middle {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

</style>

 <div>

      <img class="align-middle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">

      <span class="align-middle">
            <p>(1)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
            <p>(2)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
            <p>(3)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
            <p>(1)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
            <p>(2)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
            <p>(3)I'm in the middle of the image! thanks to CSS! hooray!</p>
      </span>
</div>
```